# Google cloud: I can not acces to my VM

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, ubuntu-server

I have problem with a google cloud virtual machine
Suddenly I am not able to acces to my VM instance from google cloud: it returs me: 
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection refused

I have run nmap and outputs 
Host is up.
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

I have modified the /etc/ssh/ssh_config, to prevent broken pip error, adding :

ServerAliveInterval 120

ServerAliveCountMax 10

to the end of that file .

1.: May anyone figuer out what is happening and how to solve it.

2. Is there any way alternative to ssh to connect to my VM instance?

thanks so much

Comment: additional information: when running ssh -v to to connect it outoputs: MacBook-Pro-de-Manel:~ manelguz$ ssh -v instance-1.europe-west1-b.test-1111
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/manelguz/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/manelguz/.ssh/config line 18: Applying options for instance-1.europe-west1-b.test-1111
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <ip> [<ip> port 22.
debug1: connect to address <ip> port 22: Connection refused

Comment: Can you explain why setting ServerAliveInternal 120 and ServerAliceCountMax 10 prevents broken pip error? Because I'm not sure what is broken pip error (Python related maybe?)

Did you try reverting the settings you've configured on ssh_config back to the old config and try to ssh again? If so, do you get the same "port 22: Connection refused" error?

Can you also provide the output of $gcloud compute firewall-rules list to check if you have a firewall rule allowing traffic on port 22?

Comment: Can you access the instance via Interactive Serial Console (as explained here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) and then provide the output of the commands:
$ ps auxw | grep ssh => to check if the service is really running (which seems to be the case, but double check does not hurt)

Go home with
$ cd
and then run and paste the output here:
$ ls -lisah .ssh/

To discard permission issues please try to SSH with a different user running $ gcloud compute ssh [USER]@example-instance

Comment: Dear Paula, How can i revert the  ssh_config without entering into the instance? I have also tried with serial port, but when i do that i am asked for a ubunto loging and pass witch i have not set, then I don't know it

Comment: You can use an startup script on the GCE instance to set a password: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

To add an startup script to a GCE instance: click on the name of the instance -> click edit -> set custom metadata like this: Key startup-script  Value  #!/bin/bash  echo -e "linuxpassword\nlinuxpassword" | passwd linuxuser

Comment: If you've never set a password for either your user or root you'll be asked twice for a new password, if you've set a password before you'll be asked first for the old password and then twice for the new password, so take this in account when using the startup script.

As explained here https://www.systutorials.com/39549/changing-linux-users-password-in-one-command-line the script to set the password can be run with or without --stdin parameter depending on the system you run the script

Comment: Perfectly, i have fixed it!  I have loggin with the serial console and set as default the ssh_config file, now i am able to ssh to my instance, thanks Paula. Moreover, if you summit your comment as an answer i will validate it for anyone els who have the same issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Summary from the comments above:***

---

1. Set a password to a user within the instance [***by setting up an startup script on the GCE instance***](http://%20%20%20cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

   - To add an startup script to a GCE instance:

     - Click on the name of the instance.
     - Click edit.
     - Set custom metadata like this:

       - **Key** *startup-script*
       - **Value** *#!/bin/bash*
         echo -e "linuxpassword\nlinuxpassword" | passwd linuxuser**

> If you've never set a password for either your user or root you'll
>   be asked twice for a new password, if you've set a password before
>   you'll be asked first for the old password and then twice for the
>   new password, so take this in account when using the startup
>   script. [**As explained here**](https://www.systutorials.com/39549/changing-linux-users-password-in-one-command-line/) the script to
>   set the password can be run with or without --stdin parameter depending on the system you run the script on.

2. Access the instance via [***Interactive Serial Console***](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).
3. Revert the settings on the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` back to the old config and try to ssh again.
4. Important note, for **security** reasons **remove the startup script** and **change the password** from within the instance once you regain access to the instance.